# final double in constructor java

Tags: java, immutability

I have trouble understanding why `double xx` and `yy` are put `final` in the constructor. Why don't I just put them `double xx` and `double yy`. Why
do they have to be `final`? I guess the whole purpose of this is
creating an `immutable` object.

```
public class Point {
private final double x, y;
private double distance; 

 public Point(final double xx, final double yy) {
  this.x = xx;
  this.y = yy;
  this.distance = -1; 
 }

}
```

Comment: There is no *need* for these parameters to be final.

Comment: Neither do they have any influence on Point being immutable.

Comment: Two above methods summarise answer but perhaps lower down in your code you may want to pass these to a thread run method ? Then they will be final. No actual significance as is.

Comment: @AfshinGhazi lower down in the code, you could refer to `Point.this.x` and `Point.this.y`, rather than making `xx` and `yy` final.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need for these parameters to be final.

There are two reasons to make parameters final:

1. To make use of them in an inner class declared in that function;
2. To prevent their values from being changed accidentally.

Clearly (1) doesn't apply.

(2) isn't necessary because it's such simple code, and you can see that it's not changing the parameters.

There is a school of thought which says that all parameters and local variables should be declared final as a matter of course, as it makes it easier to reason about the code, in the same way that using immutable types makes it easier to reason about code using them.

There is another school of thought which says that adding `final` everywhere is just unnecessary noise, and, if you are writing methods where you can't tell if the value is changing, your methods are too long.

Largely, making parameters and local variables final comes down to personal/team preference.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring x and y variables as final solves the purpose (i.e. The value must not be changed later). There is no point in declaring the constructor's parameters as final.